# Mouse double clicks when I switch the primary button

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I have this issue with a Windows 10 work computer.  When I switch the primary click from right from left (because I am a lefty) many of my clicks register a double click.

- I have tried two mice
- I have uninstalled the drives from device manager and have windows automatically add them back, recommend on a windows forum somewhere.
- If I switch back to left click I do not experience this behavior

Answer (score 0):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will reverse the functioning of the
mouse keys whenever <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is pressed:

```
Flag := 0
return
^k::DllCall("SwapMouseButton", Int,( Flag:=!Flag ) )
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the
green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)